# How does Ven work compared to Bitcoin?

Tags: currencies

The [Ven FAQ](http://www.hubculture.com/groups/dev/projects/1046/wiki/) states that Ven is a basket of currencies, but how is it determined? Is it done privately or in the style of a committee? What trade offs are there in relation to Bitcoin?

Links: [official site](http://venmoney.net/), [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ven_%28currency%29)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Bitcoin SE. Please add links to relevant information about Ven and its FAQ you are reffering to for clarity.

Comment: While we do allow questions about non-Bitcoin cryptocurrencies (a la NameCoin, IXC, TBX, etc) non-crypto currencies are off-topic here. I don't know enough about Ven to say whether it belongs or not. Does anyone out there have better knowledge to share? Simply adding "compared to Bitcoin" doesn't make things any more on topic than adding "as a programmer" on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm uncertain as well - it does appear to be a meta-currency rather than a cryptocurrency. It seems to also be a competitor to Bitcoin at a functional level. Whether it's just another fiat representation like SDRs or has something structural that Bitcoin can adopt, I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be completely unrelated (hence the close vote I just casted).

> Ven is a digital social currency used to share, buy, sell and trade in
>   the world of Hub Culture and beyond. The value of Ven floats against
>   other currencies and the price is based on a basket of currencies,
>   commodities and carbon futures.

,

> Can I trade my Ven back to national currencies like the Dollar, Euro or Pound?
>
> No

Apparently it's just a bad-old centralised virtual currency.

Nothing new, nothing special, nothing relevant. And definitely nothing related to Bitcoin.

*since I just skimmed over it, I might have got something wrong, but as far as I've read that's unlikely*

Comment: If you agree, please just cast a close vote, thanks :)

Comment: Close vote and +1 to you.